# ODBC equivalent for DAO.DBEngine.CompactDatabase

Tags: .net, ms-access, odbc, dao

Busy converting an older VB6 application which uses DAO to C# and VB.NET, using an ODBC driver. Is there an ODBC equivalent of the `CompactDatabase` function in DAO?

Later we intend to change to a different database such as MySQL or SQL Server, but for now we are still using the Access (.mdb and .accdb) single database files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Access ODBC driver cannot compact a database.

Comment: OK, thanks. How do you go about compacting the database? I could use either VB.NET or C#. Some web searches suggest invoking an external process, like the Microsoft JET engine, to do this. But there is no clear examples I could find, and I am unsure if this is the best approach. One option is to continue using DAO to compact the database until we've made the switch to a more fully-featured DB.

Comment: A .NET app can use both ODBC and DAO; they just have to co-operate. Close the ODBC connection (if any), create a `DAO.DBEngine` object, compact the database, dispose of the `DAO.DBEngine`, then re-open the ODBC connection and carry on.