# How to compact an Access database using the ODBC .accdb driver

Tags: c++, c, ms-access, odbc

Am trying to determine how to compact an Access database using the .accdb ODBC driver. Note that I'm aware of how to accomplish this using the old .mdb driver, essentially something like this:

```
  const TCHAR *Driver = TEXT("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)");
  TCHAR *DatabasePath = GetRegDBPath() ;

  _stprintf_s(Attr, sizeof(Attr)/sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("COMPACT_DB=%s%s %s%s General"), DatabasePath,
                                                  DBName,
                                                  DatabasePath,
                                                  DBName ) ;
  Ret = SQLConfigDataSource(hPar,
                            ODBC_ADD_DSN,
                            Driver,
                            Attr);
```

However substituting the Driver string with *Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)*, the call fails and calling *SQLInstallerError *to obtain error information comes back with (the rather unhelpful) message: *Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed*.

I've tried varations on the above syntax, using a different output database path, omitting the General parameter, all yield the same result.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388586/odbc-equivalent-for-dao-dbengine-compactdatabase) suggests it can't be done but I'm sceptical because it's possible to do it from the ODBC Administrator Panel. Additionally looking through the ACEODBC.DLL for string content shows the presence of the COMPACT_DB strings:

jon@monolith:~/temp$ strings -t x -e l ACEODBC.DLL | grep -i compact
395f0 COMPACT_DB
39978 COMPACT_DB=%s

All suggests it should be possibe if I knew what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Pick one language and remove the irrelevant tag. Decide if it is C or C++.

Comment: I don't see anything in that post code that would do a C + R. You have a print command with some values, and then you have a SQLConfig data source. Perhaps you post the code of SQLConfigDataSource. And I see ZERO ODBC code in your posted code. On the other hand, since you MUST have the JET (or now ACE) data engine installed, then you are then free to use the DAO database engine object to achieve this goal anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all poorly documented so I can only guess. Are you sure that "general" is valid"? Try and omit it, the docs say it's optional. Or replace it with the language constant for general, `";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0"`

Comment: Yes, I've not been able to find any info on it by various searches, hence the question."General" was valid for the old driver, I've tried a few variations, including omitting it completely all make no difference. Haven't tried the language constant you suggest, I'll give that a go next time I've got the code open.

Comment: [Documentation for SQLConfigDataSource (Access Driver)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sqlconfigdatasource-access-driver) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, ODBC was never able to compact a access database.

your posted code does a printf (simple outputs some text), and that certainly would not and does not do a compact database. the next line of code "might" C + R the datbase, but that code is not posted.

eg:

```
SQLConfigDataSource
```

And I suppose it also possible that the TEXT() method used in above might have some code, but then again, you have to provide what that TEXT() method does then.

From what I can find?

You have to create a "com" object instance of the Access database engine (JET for mdb files, and ACE for accDB files).

## Edit: The ODBC driver may be able compact

while the windows ODBC manager CAN and DOES have the ability to compact a database, it NOT 100% clear if in fact that ODBC manager is using/sending ODBC command, or that the code in the JET/ACE panel that pops up is using the DBengine compact. So, JUST because the ODBC manager has the ability to do a C+R, it still not a given that we can compact a database from the ODBC driver vs that of the manager!

However, documentation suggests this is possible, but I not seen a working example as such.

At the end of the day, this brings us back to the suggestion that a instance of the data engine object be created, and the compact method of that object be used here.

Comment: [SQLConfigDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sqlconfigdatasource-access-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) is part of the ODBC API. You'll note the link specifically mentions COMPACT_DB which as I said, works fine with the original .mdb driver. _stprintf_s & TEXT are just part of the generic text mapping routines (aka wchar/char) which is writing a formatted string, NOT printing to stdout.

Comment: Reference is under SQL server API's. That does suggest this may well be possible.  I could point out that if you have the access ODBC driver installed, then by that fact, you THEN ALSO have the ACE data engine, and creating a instance of that engine and using the compact method would work. So, while ODBC might be able to do this, if it "can" do this, then also creating a com instance of ACE and achieve this goal is possible anyway.  ODBC driver does suggest this is possible, but finding a example is proving "elusive".  The option of ACE data engine also becomes becomes possible choice.

Comment: Just to re-iterate, the code fragment I posted **does** in fact compact an Access database using the ODBC driver, I've been using it for years. It's mentioned in a few places but mostly in fairly old links and (if mentioned at all), refer to the original .mdb driver. It's when you try the same syntax with the newer, .accdb driver that it fails (along with the various incarnations of the syntax). I'm aware it can be done with the ACE data engine however I was hoping to avoid messing around with COM objects etc. if the ODBC driver can still do it. Which, there seems to be some evidence it can.

Comment: An interesting "tell tell" is that I can't get/use the compact from the ODBC panel, and that may well suggest this option is not available for accDB (ACE) files.

Comment: I think that behaviour may depend on what you have installed. I have a machine with 64-bit Office 2016 installed, if you select the 64-bit ODBC Data Source, User DSN for Access (.accdb) you most certainly **can** compact a database. But whilst that same DSN shows up in the 32-bit ODBC, the option to do anything is greyed out (& it specifically says 64-bit in the Platform column. Likewise for a machine with both 64 (Access 2010) and 32 (Access 2016) drivers, I can compact from both Data Source windows.

Comment: Well, it should be disabled if  you don't have x32 ACE installed, then only x64 can and should work.  However, my current version is not allowing a compact (x32 version) of accDB files.  As noted, this is leaning towards creating + using a instance of the DAO data engine - and as I noted, it will be installed else the odbc driver would never work in the first place.

Comment: see my edit and comments on this issue of manger allowing a C+R. While the ODBC manager panel that pops up  does have the ability to C+R, that does NOT THEN mean that via ODBC we can do a C+R. It might mean this, but so far, I not seen a working example as such.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried the "Compact" button in "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" and it seems to work for .mdb files but not for .accdb files, despite the fact that there is a "Format: Version 12.x" option. I'm wondering if this is something that may have worked years ago (e.g., circa Access 2007) but perhaps was abandoned since. (I was using the Access 2013 Database Engine.)

Comment: Also, the "Compact" button does not produce any ODBC trace activity, so whatever odbcad32.exe is doing it's not going through the ODBC Driver Manager.

Comment: "is something that may have worked years ago". I kind of thinking that also. This was/is a VERY rare option used. I can't get the accDB one to work either, and thus I think the support when using ACE as opposed to jet probably lost this feature/ability over time. However, I was surprised to see that at some point, ODBC to JET did support a C+R, but it looks like ACE does not.

Comment: The fact that there are separate "Repair" and "Compact" buttons is another clue. Those were separate operations in very old versions of Access (I'm thinking perhaps Access_97) but more current versions of Access just have a single "Compact and Repair Database" operation.

Comment: Uneartherd [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ad07b9a-55ce-49bd-8b6c-6835e73619c8/why-doesnt-this-code-work-on-64-bit-computers?forum=vcmfcatl) earlier. As has been noted the behaviour does seem to vary. The original .mdb driver CAN compact a .mdb database using the COMPACT_DB syntax. The ODBC panels (64 & 32) CAN compact a .mdb with the .accdb driver but not a .accdb. The 32-bit .accdb driver CAN compact a .mdb via COMPACT_DB but the 64-bit one can't. Neither can compact a .accdb it seems.

Comment: To add, the scenario I'm particularly keen to work is compact a .mdb under 64-bit (.accdb would be nice but not vital). I had a look at the DAO route, the examples I've seen pull in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll - but that's the 32-bit one. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for 64-bit. So this may be a non-starter as well.

Comment: The x64 bit driver ONLY comes in ACE flavor, and there was NEVER a x64 bit version of JET. Jet was the older data engine, and now the newer engine is ACE, and it can open both mdb and ACCDB files, but JET is only x32 bits. So, this again makes perfect sense, and that quite much means as we suspected all along: that the ACE driver does not support the odbc C+R command, and it probably never did. So, this means you right back to having to create a instance of the ACE data engine object, and doing the C+R that way. JET engine shipped with windows since 98 days!, ACE has to be installed.

Comment: @fridgemagnet - The 64-bit version should be "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll" if the 64-bit version of the ACE Database Engine has been installed.

Comment: That's not entirely true, as I said the 32-bit ACE driver CAN compact .mdb files. And from the control panel, both 32/64-bit ACE driver CAN compact .mdb files. Granted we don't know if the panel "cheats" in some way to do it but outwardly, it appears to. But it does appear that it can't do .accdb files. However, let's put that aside for the moment, by "ACE has to be installed" I assume you mean the AccessDatabase yes? So can you answer my comment regarding where the 64-bit DAO DLL is (which I presume is what is needed)?

Comment: hmm, don't seem to have a C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\**DAO**\ folder but if that's where it's supposed to be I'll have a play and maybe reinstall the engine again.

Comment: for ACE, I don't believe that a DAO shared folder is created, since ACE is not really DAO anymore. While it is near 100% compatible, and of course available in x64 versions (where as DAO is not). So the ACE object is now DAO.DBEngine.120. I'm looking for the location. In the mean time, for any target computer? You have to ensure that office x64 (access) is installed, or in fact install the ACE data engine - this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920  (note x32 and x64 flavors)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - My bad. I must have been looking at the (x86) folder by mistake. Using regedit to inspect HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT tells me that "DAO.DBEngine.120" is CLSID `{CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419}`, and that CLSID points to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\ACEDAO.DLL`.

Comment: +1 Gord, the ACE will be installed based on office version. Quite sure the "non" office download puts ACEDAO.dll in office 16 (when you do not have office at all installed). On my machine for access 14, then C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACDDAO.DLL --- for 16, it is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16  -- these are being posted as a FYI - (not necessary for Gord!!!).

Comment: Yes, the plan would be to install the 64-bit AccessDatabase engine (if not already present) with my app. So on the machine I'm sat on, has a 64-bit copy of Office 2016 (including Access) and yes the DLL is located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16. Handy the way they move things around like that.

Comment: it was REALLY simple when we only had x32 bit office. For MORE then 20 years, the JET data engine has and was is STILL installed by default on every copy of windows - and that even includes server editions. However, the Access team and not the windows team now owns the DAO object and ACE. So, when they create a new version, they now have to separate it into a separate folder. And now with x32 + x64? Oh, my, this is certainly a challenge now.

Comment: I checked another machine with just the ACE redistributable and the CLSID appears to be consistent, so retrieving the default value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419}\InprocServer32` should give the full path to ACEDAO.DLL whether it be in OFFICE14, OFFICE15, OFFICE16, or wherever.

Comment: Had a minor breakthrough earlier. It transpires that the 2016 AccessDatabaseEngine CAN compact .mdb files (both 32/64 bit ODBC) but the 64-bit 2010 version throws the error (this is what I was using to avoid the side-by-side issue), although the 2010 did appear to compact when using the ODBC panel.

Comment: Other interesting observation, based on the error you get back when trying to compact a .accdb file via the panel, is that it assumes the extension is .mdb. Therefore you can omit that from the COMPACT_DB & it will still work. That would in part explain why trying to compact a .accdb fails, under the hood it is always sticking a .mdb extension on the end.